# Perl - Hash Table and foreach statement

Tags: perl

I'm a bit confused on perl hashes.

I know that you can create a hash by calling:

```
my %hashTable;

$hashTable("Key") = "Value"
```

later on, if you want to retrieve the value, you can do

```
print $hashTable("Key")
```

However, I'm confused on this for loop

```
foreach (keys %{$hashTable{"key"}})
{
    print $_
}
```

without the %{$hashTable{"key"}}, it looks that it is going to print out each of the keys, but what happens if you do a % in front of a hash table?

I tried to test out this function, by giving it a key called "key", it would give me an error: can't use string ("key") as a hash reference. Is there something to do with multi-dimensional hash tables?

Comment: The only way I see that this could work is if the hash `hashTable` contained itself, as values, hashs. So `$hashTable{"key"}` would return a hash.

Comment: do you mean that there's another hash table contained in one of the key value pairs?

Comment: Yes. That in the hash `hashTable`, with the key `"key"`, that the value is itself a hash (you can mix what the value contains, whether a scalar, array or hash). And the line `keys %{$hashTable{"key"}}` returns the keys from that value hash.

Comment: AHHHH!!! Now I get it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, your iterating on the keys of a subhash.  Check out [`perldsc` - Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) for more information on such structures.

Comment: @user1157751 I wrote up an answer to summarise. I included documentation link given by Miller.

Comment: Is it just me or OP uses parentheses instead of curly braces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's happening is that you have a hash, called `%hashTable`. It has a value with the key `key`, which has for a value **another hash table**.

So the code:

```
foreach (keys %{$hashTable{"key"}})
{
    print $_
}
```

is looping through that second hash, and printing out the keys that it contains.

Here is an example using [the documentation link](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-HASHES) that [Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1733163/miller) provided:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %HoH = (
    flintstones => {
        lead => "fred",
        pal => "barney",
    },
    jetsons => {
        lead => "george",
        wife => "jane",
        "his boy" => "elroy",
    },
    simpsons => {
        lead => "homer",
        wife => "marge",
        kid => "bart",
    },
);

foreach (keys %{$HoH{"flintstones"}})
{
    print $_."\n";
}
```

This has the output:

```
lead
pal
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagine your `hashTable` as

```
key1:           <-+
    value1        |
key2:             |
    value2        += this is your hashTable, with 3x key/value
key3:             |
    value3      <-+
```

Now chaange the value for the `keyN` - so, it will not contain a *scalar* value, but one another hash, like:

```
key1:
    subkey1a: subval1a      <-+ this "HASH" is the value for the "key1".
    subkey1b: subval1b      <-|
key2:
    subkey2a: subval2a
key3:
    subkey3a: subval3a
    subkey3b: subval3b
    subkey3c: subval3c
```